# How to get UIPageControl size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

In an UIViewController I have set an UIPageController as a child controller.
 UIPageController displays correctly a Page Control panel at the bottom of the screen.

My problem is that I want to put images above the Page Control in the UIPageController and for this I would like to get the size of the Page Control panel.

How can I get the size of a Page Control panel?

I tried to resize it in the DiceTownAppDelegate but the size doesn't change (changing color works though):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary   *)launchOptions{
       UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
       pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
       pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

       pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth, kPageControlHeight);

       pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this method on your UIPageControl instance:

```
- (CGSize)sizeForNumberOfPages:(NSInteger)pageCount
```

But this won't work in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, as you won't be able to get the UIPageControl there (it doesn't exist yet). You probably should do this in your controller's `viewDidLoad`. Setting the color does work because in your code you are configuring the appearance proxy (not a specific instance), i.e. you are telling your app to use this color in all UIPageControls.

Comment: How can I get the UIPageControl instance? It doesn't seem to be reacheable from the UIPageViewController.